# Crystal Report in asp classic

Tags: iis, asp-classic

WE are using Crystal Reports Developer 8.5 to deliver crystal reports via an ASP page into the activex viewer.

We had this running perfectly on our old webserver (windows 2003 and IIS6), however we cannot produce the crystal reports on our new webserver (Windows 2008 and IIS7).  The error we are getting is below:

### Server Error in '/Reports' Application.

This type of page is not served.
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /reports/addresslabels14lpdx.asp [image]

Comment: Screenshot shows a 404 error showing the file isn't found.  If it exists and is in the right location, you might have something else blocking it.   Check your IIS settings for file types and filter types and make sure ASP is in there .  Newer versions of IIS tend to be prejudice against classic and comes setup to run .NET instead.

Comment: You can use FRT to reveal more around those 404 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis However, the platforms (Windows/Crystal Reports) you are using (either old or new) are all end of life, so before upgrading no serious discussion can be made (as most people won't use such obsolete pieces).

Comment: It's requesting a `.rpt` file, not a `.asp` file, check you allow this extension to be served.

Comment: The activeX component will load the data from crystal reports. I have experience with DynamicCompression in ASP messing that up. We had to explicitly exclude the reports folder from compressing data.